# Запретить доступ ко всему, кроме к индексному файлу

Tags: .htaccess, apache

как запретить доступа ко всему кроме к индексному файлу в корневом каталоге (`index.php`)?

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<Files "index.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

такой код не помогает и что вообще означает комбинация - Order `Allow,Deny` или Order `Deny,Allow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Order` означает последовательность действия, либо сначала разрешить потом запретить, либо наоборот.

Вот пример с комментариями:

```
# запрещает показ списка файлов
Options -Indexes
# задает обработку доступа, сначала должны идти все разрешения, потом запрет
Order allow,deny
# разрешаем доступ к index.php
<Files "index.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
# если нужно при обращении к директории открывать index.php и открываем доступ соответственно
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Files "./">
    Allow from all
</Files>
# запрещаем доступ ко всему отовсюду
Deny from all
```

То есть в данном примере после строки `Deny from all` любые `Allow` не будут давать результата.